# remove files with puppet resource tidy

Tags: design-patterns, puppet, glob, tidy

I want to delete all files that don't start with "custom". how does the glob pattern have to look like? According to https://globster.xyz/ that should be ok.

```
tidy { 'delete-original-config-files':
    path    => '/etc/httpd/conf.d/',
    recurse => true,
    matches => '!(custom*).conf',
}
```

Comment: It's not actually using a shell glob, it's using a Ruby function that's _similar_ to a shell glob. The [Puppet source code line](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/e4a654400a4c1ad3b5bc73fb558d28219a4626b2/lib/puppet/type/tidy.rb#L94) that checks if the file matches the pattern uses Ruby's [fnmatch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#fnmatch-method), which doesn't support `!` match inversion

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete all files that don't start with "custom". how does the glob pattern have to look like?

Standard shell globbing in general and the Ruby globbing function that Puppet relies upon in particular do not have either sub-patterns or a pattern-level negation operator.  As a result, you cannot write a single pattern that matches all the files you want to remove.  You can, however, write *several* patterns that collectively match all the files you want to remove, and you can configure a single `Tidy` resource with all of them:

```
tidy { 'delete-original-config-files':
    path    => '/etc/httpd/conf.d/',
    recurse => true,
    matches => ['[^c]*.conf', 'c[^u]*.conf', 'cu[^s]*.conf', 'cus[^t]*.conf', 'cust[^o]*.conf',
                'custo[^m]*.conf', 'c.conf'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your shell would need to have `shopt -s extglob` enabled to use that syntax which is unlikely to be the case.  I think the better option would be to create a cron job (or systemdtimer)

```
cron {'delete-original-config-files':
  command => '/usr/bin/find /etc/httpd/conf.d/ ! -name custom\*.conf -delete'
  minute  => '*/10',
}
```

or use exec if you really want it done via puppet

```
exec {'delete-original-config-files':
  command => '/usr/bin/find /etc/httpd/conf.d/ ! -name custom\*.conf -delete'
}
```